# How to copy a SharePoint Online Document Library from one site to another via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library

I can easily see that from the UI, there are "copy to" and "move to" options for Libraries.  But I would like to use PowerShell to copy an entire library from one site to another site, so that when I preview the new site, the library is setup with the same library title, and URL name that was provided from the original library.

Example

```
https://custom.sharepoint.com/sites/home/kitchen-library/

//kitchen-library copies to...

https://custom.sharepoint.com/sites/apartments/

//and becomes...

https://custom.sharepoint.com/sites/apartments/kitchen-library/
//and all the original kitchen-library files are copied here too
```

Is this this possible today via Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend that you use SharePoint Online OOB to implement your design.

**Please following steps:**

1.Go to the source Document library as an admin >> **Library settings** >> (General Settings) **Save document library as template**

2.On the Save as Template page, please select "**Include Content**" option

[image]

3.When you click **list template gallery**, you can see the library template you just created.

[image]

4.Select this template and click on **Download a Copy** under the **FILES** tab

[image]

5.Go to the destination **Site Settings** page >> (Web Designer Galleries) **List templates**

6.Click on **Upload Document** under the **FILES** tab, upload the template file just downloaded.

[image]

7.Then, go to **Site contents** page(classic mode). Click add an app, in the "**Find an app**" searchbox, entry template name.

[image]

8.Create a name for your new Document library. You will find that the source Document library is completely copied to the new Document library.

[image]

============================== **Updated Answer** ===============================

If you cannot see **Save documnet library/list as template** in SharePoint, please enable custom script feature.

**Please run the below PowerShell command as an admin:**

```
$TenantURL = "https://tenant-admin.sharePoint.com"
$SiteURL ="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite"
$username = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName $username -Message "Type the password:"
Connect-SPOService -URL $TenantURL -Credential $cred 
Set-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
```

Here is a similar case for your reference:

- [Save site/List as template SharePoint online missing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10-mso_o365b/save-sitelist-as-template-sharepoint-online/9e7f8c1f-4159-42b6-a6f8-96b3d4d69853)

Comment: much appreciated for all the detailed steps! I'll try this out in the next hour.

Comment: ah! I don't have enough access authority to be top admin for this library, even though I created it from scratch and I'm the owner. The link to save as template just isn't there.  Sucks.

Comment: Hi, klewis. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!